# What's wrong with this python script?

Tags: python

```
RAM=open('/root/arg2', 'r').read()
if RAM=="":
        try:
            if not sys.argv[2]=="":
                f = open("/root/arg2","a")
                f.write(sys.argv[2])
                f.close()   
    if float(RAM) > 4096:
        os.system("echo What the hell?")
```

What's wrong with the script above? The line after f.close() always gives error when compiling.
Error from compiling:

```
riki137@riki137-K70IC:~/scripts$ python -m compileall *
Compiling thatscript.py ...
Sorry: IndentationError: ('unexpected unindent', ('thatscript.py', 20, 1, '\tif float(RAM) > 4096:\n'))
```

I have tried spaces, different commands, new blank lines. None of that solved it.

Comment: This error is saying that python doesn't know why the line with the `if float` is only indented 4 spaces.  It is like having an extra close brace in other languages.  Place the if: block at same indentation level as the try: and you will see a new error that will help you along the way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to have an `except` or `finally` block for your `try`.

If you don't want to do anything in the event of an exception just put `pass` in it.

```
    try:
        if not sys.argv[2]=="":
            f = open("/root/arg2","a")
            f.write(sys.argv[2])
            f.close()
    except:
        pass
```

Failing to have this block can cause the `IndentationError` you're experiencing:

```
  try:
    foo = 1
    bar = 2
  baz = 3

  File "<pyshell#13>", line 5
    baz = 3
          ^
IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level
```

Comment: While this is one of the OP's problems, it's not the one he asked the question about, so it doesn't answer his question.  You don't mention his indentation error at all.

Comment: The missing `except`/`finally` block **is** the indentation error.  You can't just dedent a `try` block without having a corresponding `except`/`finally` block or it will throw this error.

Comment: I realize that but there's another error that you don't talk about.  According to my interpreters (v2&v3) your code throws the same error that his did.  This other error is being caused by his `if float(RAM) > 4096:` line having an indentation level too small to be in the function and too large to be out of it.

Answer (score 1):

You must follow the try block with a catch or finally block at the same tab level

Comment: Can you please give me example?

Comment: What should i put after f.close()?

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `try:` statement, as it's not doing anything.

```
RAM=open('/root/arg2', 'r').read()
if RAM=="":
    if not sys.argv[2]=="":
        f = open("/root/arg2","a")
        f.write(sys.argv[2])
        f.close()
```

Others have stated this too, but I'd be wary of just using an empty `except:` block, as this could lead you to believe things had been done that had infact failed.

Also, your next statement will fail, as if `RAM==""` then `float(RAM)` will raise a `ValueError`.  This might be an indentation problem with your question, but it should probably look something like:

```
if RAM=="":
    #Your sys.argv bit here
elif float(RAM) > 4096:
    os.system("echo What the hell?")
```